# Volume of convex body as an integral of its radial function

Tags: convex-analysis, solution-verification, intuition, volume, surface-integrals

Let $C$ be a compact convex set in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let the origin $O$ by in the internal of $C$. The gauge function $\gamma_C(.) : \mathbb{R}^d \to [0, \infty]$ of $C$ is defined as
$$
\gamma_C(x) = \inf\{t : x \in t \cdot C\}.
$$
The radial function is defined as a reciprocal of gauge function or, equivalently,
$$
1 / \gamma_C(x) = \sup\{x : t \cdot x \in C\}
$$
I'm considering the following integral:
$$
I(C) = \int_{S^{d - 1}} |1 / \gamma_C(u)| du.
$$

I have two following notions:

1. Intuitively, it looks like a volume of $C$: we integrate over all directions and summarize all distances from the origin $O$ to the boundary of $C$.
2. However, if we consider the body $a \cdot C$ for some constant $a > 0$, we will have $1 / \gamma_{a \cdot C}(u) = a \cdot 1 / \gamma_C(u)$, and:
   $$
   I(a \cdot C) = \int_{S^{d - 1}} |a \cdot 1 / \gamma_C(u)| du = a \int_{S^{d - 1}} |1 / \gamma_C(u)| du = a \cdot I(C).
   $$ From this equality, we have that $I(C)$ is not a volume of $C$ because $Vol(a \cdot C) = a^3 \cdot Vol(C)$.

So, which of (1) and (2) is wrong?

And, if (1) is wrong, the next question: can we construct a volume of $C$ from the integral of its radial function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 is wrong. For example consider the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then the integral is $\int_0^{2\pi} 1= 2\pi$. The volume, however, is of course $\pi$. The problem is, like you point out in 2, that the volume is not actually linear with respect to scaling. The integral treats the area of a disc like a rectangle on the circle, but it’s actually much more like a triangle. (With both sides depending on the scaling factor.)

The problem is that the infinitesimal volume element in spherical coordinates is not $d\rho du$ where $du = vol_{S^{d-1}}$ is the volume form of $S^{d-1}$ and $\rho$ is the radius. You need to scale with the Jacobi determinant when you change coordinates.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by this? "The integral treats the area of a disc like a rectangle on the circle, but it’s actually much more like a triangle. (With both sides depending on the scaling factor.)". Can you clarify this statement? What is a rectangle on the circle?

Comment: Fair enough, that was pretty unclear. Let $C$ be the disc of radius $a$. Then $\int_{S^1}| 1/\gamma_C(U)|du= 2\pi a$ I.e the area of a rectangle with sides $a$ and $2\pi$. The correct area/volume is however $\pi a^2=\frac{1}{2}(2\pi a) a$.

Comment: The infinitesimal volume element is as follows, right? $dV = \rho^2 sin \theta d\rho d\phi d\theta = \rho^2 d\rho du$. Then we can say that volume is $\int_{S^{d - 1}} \int_0^\rho \rho^2 d\rho du = \frac{1}{3} \int_{S^{d - 1}} \rho^3 du = \frac{1}{3} \int_{S^{d - 1}} |1 / \gamma_C(u)|^3 du$. Is this correct?

Comment: I think this is correct if $d=3$.

Comment: So, do you have a doubt that this is correct for $d > 3$?

Comment: Yes, the volume element will have $\rho^{d-1}$ as a factor.

Comment: OK, thank you very much for this answer!